# How to set port number for Elasticsearch running in Docker in host network mode

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I need to change the port number of Elasticsearch that is running in Docker in host network mode.

Port mapping does not apply in host network mode.

The relevent part of my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
services:
  elasticsearch_place_data:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elasticsearch_place_data
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - http.host=0.0.0.0
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
    - es_place_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks_mode: host
```

Comment: Seems like you can probably set it via `http.port`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings

Comment: depends, do you mean the http or the transport port?

Comment: @MarkWalkom, I need to change the http port, but ideally it would be good to be able to change both.

Comment: @erik258, thanks, it works. Looks like you can change both the http and transport port using that environment var. (I magically managed to overlook this in the doc while looking for solution - needed more coffee, I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use `http.port` and `transport.port` as per [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/modules-network.html#common-network-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are only two options:

- Create own modified docker image of ELasticsearch with exposed port changed.
- Use external port-forwarding. e.g. ssh tunnel. (justified in very rare cases)

Comment: that doesn't seem right McLay.  Sounds like `http.port` works fine.